# Stimulus check- haven't filled 2019 taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, covid-19, stimulus

I haven't filed for 2019 yet. Everything I've found online says that if you haven't filed for 2019 before the checks are sent out, they'll look at your 2018 taxes, but I didn't file for 2018 either because I wasn't working in the US (I'm not an American). I'd like to file my taxes for 2019 closer to the tax deadline. If I do that, will I not get the stimulus check?

Comment: You may have to wait for an answer until the bill actually becomes law. It passed the senate but could still get held up or revised in the house. At this point everything is conjecture and hear-say until we get the actual text of the bill.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for speculation about possible future law.

Comment: You can read the bill here as passed by the Senate https://apps.npr.org/documents/document.html?id=6819239-FINAL-FINAL-CARES-ACT

Can it really get revised by the house? Seems strange to me that the Senate could pass something and then it gets changed further down the pipeline.

Comment: @Brimby It can be modified by the House, and then the Senate would have to approve the changes.

Comment: @yoozer8 sorry, I wasn't sure this was a speculative question. Was hoping there was a good answer out there already!

Comment: The bill has been signed into law, so it is no longer speculative.

Comment: the conclusion so far is that if I don't file my taxes for 2019 now, I will likely just not get the check ever.

Comment: Why file it later?

Answer (score 4):

According to the final version of the bill, this "stimulus check" is really a pre-payment of a refundable 2020 tax credit. So if you don't get the check this year, you can file your 2020 taxes next year and claim the credit (assuming you still meet the income requirements).

Comment: Thanks. This is also true if my 2020 income will be way over 75K?

Comment: @jgozal  You may get a phase out amount, zero if it is over 99K if filling single.

Comment: @jgozal: In that case, you might just want to file your 2019 return now.  Unless you're a medical professional or something, you probably have plenty of free time these days.

Comment: @PeteB. yeah my 2020 income will be way over 99K.

Comment: @jamesqf not as much as much free time as I'd like, fortunately. But there's a different reason for me wanting to file later.

Comment: If what this answer says is true then you won't get the money either way because you won't get the refundable credit and so you'll have to pay it back

Comment: @xyious That's not completely clear at this point, but I think most people expect you will not have to repay the check if your income is higher in 2020.